# Insert the table environment into the tcolorbox environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, tcolorbox

Is possible insert the `table` environment into the `tcolorbox` environment, made available by the package `tcolorbox`?

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

% Generali
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Riquadri
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title= Box1: Title.]
%\begin{table}[tb]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to insert a `table` with `caption` and `label`?

Comment: You can use `\captionof{table}{...}` from the `caption` package.

Comment: I like this one
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274338/how-to-make-a-table-tabular-appears-in-a-tcolorbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tcolorbox` (as its name suggests) is a box; `table` is a float, and inside a box, a float is stuck ... which is why it doesn't work.

just use the tabular, and give it a caption using `\captionof` from `capt-of.sty` or (iirc) `caption.sty` (which has so many options i'm never quite sure).

Answer (score 6):

`tcolorbox`-es can also `float` and you can declare `tcolorboxes` to be referenced as `figures` and `tables`. Following code declares a floating `mytable` box. The title will be preceded by `Table #` and `label` option can be used for references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{mytable}[2][]{float=htb, halign=center,  title={#2}, every float=\centering, #1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mytable}[float=t, label=myref]{This is a floating box}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}
\end{mytable}

{\Large As you can see in table~\ref{myref} \dots}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helped so much at the very moment!

Answer (score 3):

You can't put a table inside a box. But you can do the reverse -- put a box inside a table:

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

% Generali
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Riquadri
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tb]
\caption{This is table}
\label{tab:mytable}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title= Box1: Title.]
%\begin{table}[tb]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{table}

As per Table~\ref{tab:mytable}, this works.

\end{document}
```

[image]