# How to make a Table/tabular appears in a tcolorbox?

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

I want to use tables ( with caption and label) inside tbox, but The SAME table that appears outside the tbox, doesn´t appear inside.

How could I do?, What´s the problem?

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor} % dddd%
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}   %para crear referencias
% poner las dos siguientes líneas despues de begin- document   % Type the next two lines after begin-document
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{table}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box, using \emph{tcolorbox} package.}]

\tcblower

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{table}



\textbf{Question}
\begin{itemize}
  \item What's ...?
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you can't use floats inside `tcolorbox`. If you remove the `table` environment it will work.

Comment: You can use `\captionof{table}{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}` to get captions outside the table environment (but check the numbering if you mix floats and non-floats)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Float` package with `H` option for `table` environment

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor} % dddd%
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}   %para crear referencias
% poner las dos siguientes líneas despues de begin- document   % Type the next two lines after begin-document
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{table}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box, using \emph{tcolorbox} package.}]

\tcblower

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}

\end{table}

\textbf{Question}
\begin{itemize}
  \item What's ...?
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this option!

Answer (score 3):

`table` is a float and you cant put a float inside a `minipage` or `box` (like `tcolorbox`). But the reverse is possible → put the `tcolorbox` inside the `table`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor} % dddd%
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}   %para crear referencias
% poner las dos siguientes líneas despues de begin- document   % Type the next two lines after begin-document
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{table}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title={\large In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box, using \emph{tcolorbox} package.}]

\tcblower  %% why this line?

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}


\textbf{Question}
\begin{itemize}
  \item What's ...?
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW `\large{...}` should be `{\large .... }`