# Error: Not in outer par mode: table inside tcolorbox

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

i use code from topic: [How to make a Table/tabular appears in a tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274338/how-to-make-a-table-tabular-appears-in-a-tcolorbox)

But error "Not in outer par mode" and table does not appear.

Minimal Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor} % dddd%
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box}]

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{table}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]
How can i fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You should not insert float `table` into box. Remove it and for caption use `\captionof` (defined in the `caption` and in `capt-of` package) command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,
               x11names,table]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box}]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\captionof{figure}{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`tcolorbox` allows to convert your figures and tables into nice floating colourful boxes. `blend into=tables` option uses the `tcolorbox` title as caption and adds the table counter and the caption into `listoftables`. If you prefer that tcolorbox adjust to table size, `capture=hbox` does it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{mytable}[2][]{float=htb, title={#2}, 
     every float=\centering, before upper=\centering, #1}    

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{mytable}{A nice floating table in tcolorbox format}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{mytable}

\begin{mytable}[capture=hbox, colback=red!10, colframe=red!40!black]{Another nice floating table in tcolorbox format}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution in the `tcolorbox` spirit, but your screenshot doesn't correspond to your code. Indeed, your code has `capture=hbox` unconditionally in the options for `\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{mytable}{...}`, thus both boxes have `capture=hbox`. Besides, I would simplify the preamble *a lot*: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{mytable}[2][]{
  float=htb, title={#2}, every float=\centering, #1}` is enough for the sample code inside  the `document` environment.

Comment: @frougon You're right. I modified the code on my computer but I did no copy the whole code on this site. I've corrected it. About the preamble, you are also right, but I just used the original one.

Comment: Users often write their whole preamble in the questions, but I generally clean these up when answering (unless there is really document contents that depends on the preamble). Otherwise, it's really difficult to exploit answers with an overly complex preamble: it takes time to filter out what is useless, and the users who need answers most don't even know they have to do so nor how to do it; they will copy huge preambles to their documents, and in the end they will load 100 packages, of which they use 10. You know the problems this creates.

Comment: Regarding [this edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/502898/revisions), didn't you want `before upper` rather than `after upper`?

Comment: @frougon Ups! you're right again! Thank you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the edit. I gave you my +1 now, but you still have unneeded `hyperref` (and `a4paper` and `12pt`)...

Answer (score 2):

You want to float the `tcolorbox`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor} % dddd%
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=gray!5!white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box}
]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And no, you don't want just `h!`, because it's highly unlikely that a table will fit at the “right spot”. Don't worry if it goes somewhere else, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)