# Conflict between main.tex and input child.tex

Tags: tables

When I run `child.tex`, then table created with right formatting.

When I run `main.tex`, with `\input{child.tex}`, then table in `child.tex` created with wrong formatting.

`child.tex` code from: [Error: Not in outer par mode: table inside tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502860/error-not-in-outer-par-mode-table-inside-tcolorbox)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,
               x11names,table]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box}]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\captionof{figure}{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

And in `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
a lot of usepackage
\begin{document}
\input{child.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I clear format of `main.tex` inside `child.tex`?

Comment: No `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and calls for packages in `child.tex` and you can compile !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can **not** have two `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` commands in one TeX code!

Please see the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have both TeX codes in one compiling MWE, you do **not need** to use `filecontents` in your code!) and please see the comments in code for `main.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{child.tex}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box}]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\captionof{figure}{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{filecontents}


% your code main.tex following % <===========================================
\documentclass[%
  12pt,a4paper,
  x11names,table
]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox} % all needed packages for child.tex have to be called here!
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\input{child.tex} % only code for environment tcolorbox
\end{document}
```

giving you the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

You get the same output with following both files.

First `child.tex`:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box}]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a& b & T/F & dif\\ \hline
1 & 2 & False & -1\\
2 & 4 & False & -2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\captionof{figure}{Caption Table}\label{tab:table-out}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

and second `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[%
  12pt,a4paper,
  x11names,table
]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\input{child.tex}
\end{document}
```

Please do us and yourself a favour and read the documentation of package `filecontents` for example by typing `texdoc filecontents` in your terminal/console and press then enter ...  This package is very helpful for building MWE for testing purposes like in your case ...

Comment: thank for your comment. I use and can create this table. But some error like https://ibb.co/tx49XJJ . And how can i remove this line "ilecontents Child.tex" thanks

Comment: @latexforti Please see my updated answer ...