# Include footnote to table that is within tcolorbox

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

I have put a table inside a tcolorbox using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502860/error-not-in-outer-par-mode-table-inside-tcolorbox) post by @Ignasi.

However, I am having trouble putting a footnote—or really any text—below the table. Whatever text I write after `\end{tabular}` is put to the RIGHT of the table, but I want this text to be BELOW the table.

If possible, I would like to keep the tcolorbox within a minipage, as I have found it easier to align 2 minipages than to align 2 tcolorboxs. (But maybe there is an easy way to align 2 tcolorboxs, and I am just ignorant of it.)

Any thoughts on how to get text that is written after the `\end{tabular}` command to appear BELOW the table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=19mm, right=19mm,top=18mm,bottom=18mm,includehead=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox, varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{TableStyle1}[2][]{title={#2}, before upper=\centering, #1}    

\begin{document}




Some introductory text....


\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\begin{TableStyle1}[capture=hbox, colback=white, colframe=blue!15, coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries]{Proposed frequency of CT scans}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3mm}
\begin{tabular}{m{24mm} m{24mm} m{16mm}}

Date & Scan & mSv \\
\midrule
early Jan 2024 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
May 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Nov 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2025 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
Aug 2026 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Aug 2027 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2028 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
\textbf{TOTAL*}& & \textbf{176 mSv} \\
\end{tabular}
*This total includes the 48 mSv already obtained from previous scans.
\end{TableStyle1}
\vspace{5mm}
\end{minipage}


Some more text....

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am getting currently:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn off `[collect=hbox]`.  All the minpage does is set the width. I put the "footnote" inside a `\parbox` to turn off the centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=19mm, right=19mm,top=18mm,bottom=18mm,includehead=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox, varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{TableStyle1}[2][]{title={#2}, before upper=\centering, #1}    

\begin{document}




Some introductory text....


\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}% set width of title
\begin{TableStyle1}[colback=white, colframe=blue!15, coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries]{Proposed frequency of CT scans}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3mm}
\begin{tabular}{m{24mm} m{24mm} m{16mm}}

Date & Scan & mSv \\
\midrule
early Jan 2024 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
May 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Nov 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2025 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
Aug 2026 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Aug 2027 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2028 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
\textbf{TOTAL*}& & \textbf{176 mSv} \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\par\medskip
%\hrule% show available space
\parbox{\textwidth}{% turn off centering
*This total includes the 48 mSv already obtained from previous scans.}
\end{TableStyle1}
\vspace{5mm}
\end{minipage}


Some more text....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. 

To be honest, I did not really understand the command `[capture=hbox]` when I included that command in my code. What does this command do?

Comment: It puts the contents into a single line of text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\footnote`, but without `capture=hbox`.

With `minipage{0.33\linewidth]`, we have an `Overfull \hbox` of more than 97pt. You need `0.53\linewidth` or reduce the widths of the table (you can also use the `tabularx` or `tabularray` packages)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=19mm, right=19mm,top=18mm,bottom=18mm,includehead=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox, varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{TableStyle1}[2][]{title={#2}, before upper=\centering, #1}    
\begin{document}
Some introductory text....

\begin{minipage}{0.53\linewidth}%<-- this line
\begin{TableStyle1}[colback=white, colframe=blue!15, coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries]{Proposed frequency of CT scans}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3mm}
\begin{tabular}{m{24mm} m{24mm} m{16mm}}

Date & Scan & mSv \\
\midrule
early Jan 2024 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
May 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Nov 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2025 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
Aug 2026 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Aug 2027 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2028 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
\textbf{TOTAL\footnote{This total includes the 48 mSv already obtained from previous scans.}}& & \textbf{176 mSv} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{TableStyle1}
\vspace{5mm}
\end{minipage}%

Some more text....
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\tabularnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=19mm, right=19mm,top=18mm,bottom=18mm,includehead=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox, varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{TableStyle1}[2][]{title={#2}, before upper=\centering, #1}    
\begin{document}
Some introductory text....

\begin{minipage}{0.53\linewidth}%<-- this line
\begin{TableStyle1}[capture=hbox,colback=white, colframe=blue!15, coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries]{Proposed frequency of CT scans}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3mm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{24mm} m{24mm} m{16mm}}

Date & Scan & mSv \\
\midrule
early Jan 2024 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
May 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Nov 2024 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2025 & CT CAP & 24 mSv \\
Aug 2026 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
Aug 2027 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv\\
Aug 2028 & CT AP | CXR & 16 mSv \\
\textbf{TOTAL\tabularnote{This total includes the 48 mSv already obtained from previous scans.}}& & \textbf{176 mSv} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{TableStyle1}
\vspace{5mm}
\end{minipage}%

Some more text....
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]